# Central-by-cyclic

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, centralisers

This is a following-up question of [this.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453609/cece-cap-czu-1-or-p/453627?noredirect=1#comment1173769_453627)

Lemma 2.4 from Robert Griess' paper "Elementary abelian $p$-subgroups of algebraic groups" states:

(i) Let $T$ be a finite $p$-group whose Frattini subgroup is cyclic and central. Then $T'$ has order $1$ or $p$ and there are subgroups $X, Y$ such that $T$ = $X\circ Y$ where $X$ is extraspecial and $Y$ has an abelian maximal subgroup and $\Omega_1(Y)$ is elementary abelian.

(ii) If $T/T'$ is elementary abelian, $Y$ is of the form $p^r$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times p^r$.

The proof for (i):

Notice that $T'$ has order 1 or $p$. The abelian case is trivial, so we assume that $T'$ has order $p$. Let $U \ge T'$ satisfy $U/T'=\Omega_1(T/T')$. Let $E$ be an extraspecial subgroup of $U$ such that $U=Z(U)E$ where $Z(U)$ denotes the center. Then, $[E,T]=T'=Z(E)$ implies that $T=C(E)E$ where $C(E)$ denotes the centralizer. Since $T/U$ is cyclic and $T'$ has order $p$, we see that $|C(E):C(E)\cap C(Z(U))|=1$ or $p$. Since the Frattini subgroup of $T$ is cyclic, the same is true for subgroups and quotients, whence $C(E)\cap C(Z(U))$ is central-by-cyclic, hence abelian. Take $X=E$ and $Y=C(E)$.

Question:
I don't really understand the last piece of the argument. Does "being central-by-cyclic" mean being cyclic after quotient out the center?  Of which group is the same true for subgroups and quotients? The group $C(E)\cap C(Z(U))$? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: "central-by-cyclic" has been confirmed. How to go from $|C(E):C(E)\cap C(Z(U))|=1$ or $p$ to $C(E)\cap C(Z(U))$ being central-by-cyclic is still not clear to me..

Comment: I think Griess intends here to mean that $C(E) \cap C(Z(U))$ modulo its center is cyclic. I think most finite group-theorists would interpret the statement "$G$ is central by cyclic" to mean that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, which is what Griess is doing here. And with that interpretation, it is standard that a central by cyclic group is Abelian, as Griess concludes.

Comment: Yes, I agree. thank you for the input. Although I'm still not clear how to go from $|C(E):C(E)\cap C(Z(U))|=1$ or $p$ to $C(E)\cap C(Z(U))$ being central by cyclic.

Comment: Does he mean the whole argument from the very beginning can be applied to the intersection group?